# Python typing: how to declare a variable that is either a path-like object (os.path) or a Path (pathlib)

Tags: python, python-typing, pathlib

I understand that module pathlib is new since Python 3.4 and I'm trying to use it as much as possible, but I have a lot of existing code with: "import os.path". I'm also trying to add typing to my code since a few weeks, but I'm still learning how to do it. I don't understand yet how to declare a variable with an ambiguous type - casu quo a variable which is either a so-called path-like object (os.path) or a Path (pathlib). Such a variable could then be used as input for e.g. an open statement. I tried this in a test module called test_typevar:

```
from pathlib import Path
from typing import TypeVar
from some_module import some_function

PathLike = TypeVar("PathLike", str, Path)
fpath: PathLike
line: str

# Now suppose fpath is returned by some code and it's either a Path or a path-like object:
fpath = some_function()
with open(fpath, "rt") as f:
    line = f.readline()
    ...
```

This is the error statement I'm getting:
error: Type variable "test_typevar.PathLike" is unbound
note: (Hint: Use "Generic[PathLike]" or "Protocol[PathLike]" base class to bind "PathLike" inside a class)
note: (Hint: Use "PathLike" in function signature to bind "PathLike" inside a function)

Can anybody explain things further?

Comment: Why not just `Union[Path, str]` (or `Path | str`) in recent Python versions?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [documentation for open()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open), it accepts any of {`str`, `bytes`, `os.PathLike` object} for its filename argument.

To declare a function that accepts any of these:

```
import os

def dosomething(fname_arg : str | bytes | os.PathLike):
    fname = os.fspath(fname_arg)   
    # fname = str(fname_arg) # would also work
```

Answer (score -1):

I believe that `os.PathLike` is meant for general purposes. It can be a `str` or a `pathlib.Path`.

`PathLike` type is a type hint used to indicate an object that can be used to represent a file path or a file-like object. It is often used as a generic type hint to accept different types that can be treated as paths. It allows flexibility by accepting different types of path representations,: strings, `pathlib.Path`, or custom objects that behave like paths.

from [os' documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.PathLike):

> class os.PathLike
> An abstract base class for objects representing a file system path, e.g. pathlib.PurePath.

from os' source code:

> Abstract base class for implementing the file system path protocol.

Comment: `str` is not a subtype of `os.PathLike`, so you still need to use a union.

Comment: @velikodniy he is asking about type hinting, not about verifying an instance of.I believe that in type hinting, os.PathLike means that the object supports str and pathlib.Path as per the documentation states.

Comment: In any case the type hint should match the actual type. If `str` isn't a subtype it might mislead the reader. Also, a type checker would show an error.

Answer (score -3):

Well you can simply use:

```
import pathlib
a = pathlib.PurePath("somepath")
a
returns: PureWindowsPath('somepath')

b = pathlib.Path("somepath")
b

returns: WindowsPath('somepath')

c = pathlib.PurePosixPath("somepath")
c
returns: PurePosixPath('somepath')
```

You can as well combine paths in brackes seperated with comma. Such as `pathlib.Path(some path, next directory, finaly directory)` and it will connets paths into one.

**Know:** PurePath is for windows, PurePosixPath is for UNIX and Path is for both, you can simply use Path or detect which OS you are on and then use proper PathType.

It will accept  `\\sss\\sss\\` path WINDOWS syntax and `/sss/sss/` path UNIX syntax.

**Edit:** Path(..) should automaticly detect OS type so that's why you can see WindowsPath as return value (so it does not confuse you).

Comment: Thanks for the effort. Sorry, the question is not about the use of pathlib classes, but about how to apply typing to the instances thereof.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).